# Change resolution of Session 0

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, winapi, service

I want to make an application where I can take pictures of a Gui-application that is being run as a Windows Service. The Gui-application that I have has a resolution of `1280x800`. When I take a picture inside the windows service, the picture has a resolution of `1024X768`.

When I looked online I came across the following [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fea1b627-decd-40d7-877b-b34ea5499677/change-screen-resolution-in-session-0-windows-server-20122012r2?forum=winservergen) that says that the resolution of `Session 0` is `1024x768`.

Can we change the resolution of `Session 0`?

---

*use case: I send data to the application by means of a TCP connection. Via messages like WM_PAINT I can retrieve a picture of how the GUI would look like when it's running as an application(not in a service)*

Comment: _"... a GUI-application that is being run as a Windows Service ..."_ - what do you mean by that? Windows services doesn't have any GUI.

Comment: That is correct in the sense that you can have no user interaction. But I send data to the application by means of a TCP connection. Via messages like WM_PAINT I can retrieve a picture of how the GUI would look like when it's running as an application(not in a service) .

Comment: I haven't had a need to experiment with it, but it makes sense to me that the display resolution of a non-interactive window station would be fixed at some base value such as 1024x768. Maybe move the window and stitch together the final screenshot from four 640x400 images.

Comment: While this could be a solution ( got to test this first ) . I think it will resize the Gui, and since the gui is not made to be shrinked, it will look different . The best solution ( if possible) is if the resolution of session 0 could be increased.

Comment: Then you have to ask yourself, what if another application also wants to do this? Who wins? Can you move this window around and take partial screenshots?

Comment: "what if another application also wants to do this?" For me that is not really the question. This could maybe lead to a problem if not taken care of this, but I just want to know if it is possible to change the resolution of Session 0. If this is not possible, I should reconsider the design of my service with the solutions you proposed.

Comment: @YLohrmnn - Why do you want the application to be run as a service? If this is for testing purposes and you need a secure method: a simpler approach might be to have your application running in a VM that does not get locked and lock the workstation the VM runs on.

Comment: Nevertheless, I'm curious if it can be done. Perhaps an alternative route is to ask [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/author/oldnewthing). I would be surprised if he can't come up with a definitive answer.

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers : "Why do you want the application to be run as a service?" , this is considered a "design requirement". The server where the service would be running(in the future) is not mine.

Comment: Fair enough and I'm not trying to pollute your question but why do you need to take pictures of it while running?

Comment: @YLohrmnn The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/design/dn653293(v=vs.85)) says that Session 0 reports the correct results for the system. So have you get different value when changing the system resolution setting?  I am wondering why you need check the GUI when the application running as a service.

Comment: @ Rita Han - MSFT , my system resolution is 1920x1080 which is way above the 1024x768 so that will not change a thing.